# Javascript not enabled error in Firefox and Chrome while using Google Oauth

Tags: javascript, redirect, authentication, oauth

I am trying google oAuth authentication for liferay user. the URL am using for Google OAuth is

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=myClientId&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8090/c/login/oauth2callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

It redirects me to the google login page(if the user not logged in) and then the authorization page.

After I say allow, browser redirects me to

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/noscript
```

saying

```
You've reached this page because we have detected that Javascript is disabled in your browser. The page you attempted to load cannot display properly if scripts are disabled.

Please enable scripts and retry the operation or go back in your browser
```

It happens only in Firefox(am using 16.0.2, even in earlier versions it was happening) and chrome(22). It works fine in IE.

What would be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is some extenshion blocking js,
Try again in incogonito window, if oAuth OK:
For the latest installed extensions, you can select "Allow in incognito", then try incogonito view agian, if oAuth Fail, then remove the extension.
I just found one weired extension, remove it, then OK!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to [enable scripts in Chrome](http://lifehacker.com/5180010/enable-user-scripts-in-google-chrome)?

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Yes the javascript is enabled in both the browsers, moreover this is working in IE, but not in others why?

Comment: well, definitely something in http://localhost:8090/c/login/oauth2callback uses scripts that causes your Firefox and Chrome to block it. On IE you have probably allowed something that is disabled on the others - configuration checks, my friend...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you don't have the configure settings good enough. Go to about:config in Mozilla and then go down to the VERY last one and then put it to 0.